# Kronecker Delta and Constants

Tags: summation, kronecker-delta

I have a small question and I hope I make this clear.

Would one distribute the Kronecker Delta as follows?

$\sum_{j}^n\     ( C + x_j ) \delta_{ij}$

$= \sum_{j}^n\     ( C\delta_{ij} + x_j\delta_{ij} ) $

$= C +  \sum_{j}^n\     x_j\delta_{ij} ) $

I believe the answer to be only :  $ \ \ x_i $

But I can not reason why the C term should vanish. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I hope $\delta_{i}j $ should be written as $\delta_{ij} $. Is it right?

Comment: @민찬홍 I think you are right, since the Kronecker delta is a function of two arguments.

Comment: I think $C+x_{i} $ is right. The constant C should not be vanished. Let $y_{j}=C+x_{j} $. Then the sum equals to $y_{i}$.

Comment: Yes to the first comment, I will edit.

Comment: I do not understand your justification  민찬홍

Comment: I made another small edit, i forgot a + sign in the last equation

Comment: I actually believe that since there is no index on the constant, i != always, and therefore the constant disappears